# Updating to a linked SQL Table

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

I have a form which writes data to a linked SQL table, and one of the functions is an EDIT function, but when I make the edits and resubmit the data I get the error

```
Run Time Error 3073 Operation Must Use an Updateable Query
```

I have used this code before on normal Access tables housed in the database where the form is and it works fine, do I need to make some alterations to the code since it is editing the data on a linked SQL table? The code is as follows?

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE dbo_AC_CD_Data_Form " & _
"SET EmployeeID='" & Me.txtEmpID & "'" & _
", EmployeeName='" & Me.txtEmpName & "'" & _
", Gender='" & Me.cboGender & "'" & _
", EEOC='" & Me.cboEEOC & "'" & _
", ReadinessLevel='" & Me.cboReadyLvl & "'" & _
", Division='" & Me.cboDivision & "'" & _
", Center='" & Me.txtCenter & "'" & _
", EmployeeFeedback='" & Me.txtFeedback & "'" & _
", DevelopmentForEmployee='" & Me.txtDevelopment & "'" & _
", Justification='" & Me.txtJustification & "'" & _
", Changed ='" & Me.cboChanged & "'" & _
" WHERE EmployeeID='" & Me.txtEmpID & "'"
```

Comment: Linked tables will be readonly if Access can't determine the primary key. Try to open the table in design mode inside Access and see if there is a primary key.

Comment: There is no primary key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the linked table in Access and link it again. The wizard should ask to you for a primary key. Select the field or fields that compound the primary key.

Note that is not necessary that the original table have a pk (This is usually happen linking views).

Comment: I did that but now it is not make the actual changes I am trying to make.

Comment: What type of database is the source of the table? Some source types are always readonly

Comment: It is just a SQL Server Table

Comment: I do not get the error anymore but when I hit the update button, nothing happens to the data.

Comment: Ok I just did something, now the only thing I cannot edit is the field which is designated as the primary key.

Comment: yes, primary keys are considered as read only in linked tables. I'm glad you found the solution.